# Python 3 function for counting words in a txt file is giving wrong answer for one word...why?

Tags: python

I am supposed to be making a word/count dictionary for a given txt file. The count part is correct aside from one word in the txt file getting skipped over twice. Why is this? It is like it is skipping over the instances of "we" that are capitalized despite me trying to use .lower() on each word. This is the text it is supposed to count words in:

We are not what we should be 
We are not what we need to be 
But at least we are not what we used to be 
-- Football Coach

However when I change the txt file so the uppercase "We"s are lowercase, it will count them just fine. All of the other words starting with uppercase letters are getting lowercased as they should, but not those "We"s. Why is .lower() not working on those "We"s, but it is working on everything else that starts with an uppercase letter? It is counting only 4 "we"s instead of 6. Everything else is correct and it also has the correct overall word count, so I don't understand what is wrong. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
def create_word_dict(filename):
    """Returns a word/count dict for the given file."""
    import collections
    frequency = {}
    with open(filename) as text:
        for word in text.read().split():
            if word in frequency:
                frequency[word.lower()] += 1
            else:
                frequency[word.lower()] = 1

        new_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(frequency.items()))
        return (dict(new_dict))
```

Comment: `if word in frequency` — You're not converting to lower case here.

Comment: Since you're already importing collections, why not use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: @khelwood - Thank you! That was it.

Answer (score 0):

You only put lower case words in your dictionary. So when `word` is "We", then `if word in frequency` is false, even if "we" is actually in the dictionary. That will throw off your counts.

Since you're already importing collections, why not use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

```
with open(filename) as text:
    frequency = collections.Counter(text.read().lower().split())
```